# Connecting oracle through Batch

Tags: oracle10g, batch-file

I am trying to connect to oracle and execute one query 
I have created  abc.BAT

```
   @ECHO off
   sqlplus -S scott/tiger@orcl 

  ECHO SPOOL text.out
  select * from emp;
  ECHO SPOOL OFF
```

But i am not able to get any output when i execute abc.bat ,Whats wrong in this?

Comment: The s option tells sql+ to keep silent about itself, which is the option to use for such report things. But for troubleshooting, I would advise you to remove the "-s" to see the sql+ response. Perhaps you can discern the problem from that output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want to separate the SQL*Plus commands from the BAT file.

For example, if you create a SQL*Plus script (abc.sql)

```
C:\Users\jcave>type abc.sql
spool text.out;
select * from emp;
spool off;
exit;
```

And then create a batch file that calls SQL*Plus and passes in the SQL*Plus script you just created (abc.bat)

```
C:\Users\jcave>type abc.bat
sqlplus scott/tiger @abc.sql
```

Then when you invoke the BAT file, you'll get the output you want

```
C:\Users\jcave>abc.bat

C:\Users\jcave>sqlplus scott/tiger @abc.sql

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue Jan 24 14:37:17 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options


     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        801
        20

      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1601        300
        30

      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81       1251        500
        30


     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2976
        20

      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-81       1251       1400
        30

      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81       2851
        30


     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81       2451
        10

      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 19-APR-87       3001
        20

      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-81       5001
        10


     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-81       1501          0
        30

      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 23-MAY-87       1101
        20

      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-DEC-81        951
        30


     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-81       3001
        20

      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-82       1301
        10


14 rows selected.

Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

C:\Users\jcave>type text.out

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        801
        20

      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1601        300
        30

      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81       1251        500
        30


     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2976
        20

      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-81       1251       1400
        30

      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81       2851
        30


     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81       2451
        10

      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 19-APR-87       3001
        20

      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-81       5001
        10


     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-81       1501          0
        30

      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 23-MAY-87       1101
        20

      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-DEC-81        951
        30


     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-81       3001
        20

      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-82       1301
        10


14 rows selected.
```